# ¿Comó descargar una imagen y comprimirla en ZIP?

Tags: java, java-ee, url, descarga

Buenas Tardes,

Tengo este código:

```
try{

    java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("http://mas.lne.es/fotos/img/2007/10/62/203093470447035b9bc5a095.43783284-foto_verano.jpg);
    URLConnection urlCon = url.openConnection();
    System.out.println(urlCon.getContentType());
    InputStream is = urlCon.getInputStream()
    //FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\estudiante.cda\\Downloads\\Fuentes.zip");
    ZipOutputStream fos = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\estudiante.cda\\Downloads\\Fuentes.zip"));

    // name the file inside the zip  file 
    fos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("Foto.jpg")); 
    byte[] array = new byte[4096];
    int leido = is.read(array);
    while(leido > 1){

        fos.write(array,0,leido);
        leido = is.read(array);
    }
    is.close();
    fos.close();
            }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

     }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Y me sale error es decir no ejecuta!
Muchas Gracias.

Comment: en la url te faltan las comillas del final

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El url definido debe ser especificado como string entre comillas dobles:

```
java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL("http://mas.lne.es/fotos/img/2007/10/62/203093470447035b9bc5a095.43783284-foto_verano.jpg");
```

Comment: ps  tambien el  `;`

Comment: gracias :3 te lo agradezo :3